# How upload video by appengine java Google Cloud Plataform

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have a java application that provides an endpoint and receives a video file (approximately 600 mb) running in my local application, I can receive the video and upload it to the GCP bucket, but when this scenario happens in the application that is in the APP ENGINE, an error occurs, I receive an HTTP 413. Looking at the documentation, APP ENGINE has a limit of 32mb.

can anyone help me with where I can upload my application to the GCP structure so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading large video file to Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251393/uploading-large-video-file-to-google-app-engine)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.