# Handling large file uploads with Flask

Tags: python, file-upload, flask, twisted, werkzeug

What would be the best way to handle very large file uploads (1 GB +) with Flask?

My application essentially takes multiple files assigns them one unique file number and then saves it on the server depending on where the user selected.

**How can we run file uploads as a background task so the user does not have the browser spin for 1hour and can instead proceed to the next page right away?**

- Flask development server is able to take massive files (50gb took 1.5 hours, upload was quick but writing the file into a blank file was painfully slow)
- If I wrap the app with Twisted, the app crashes on large files
- I've tried using Celery with Redis but this doesn't seem to be an option with posted uploads
- I'm on Windows and have fewer options for webservers

Comment: Perhaps a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048355/large-file-upload-in-flask) may help you.

Comment: Thanks. A key issue is that upload speeds are very fast (local network) however the file write takes a very long time. I understand there is an option to stream files, but does this work for uploads?

Comment: Yes, and that link could be the answer. But, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040706/streaming-file-upload-using-bottle-or-flask-or-similar) you could get mor info ;-)

Comment: @Infinity8, did you solve your problem?

Comment: Try using [Web Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) with [resumable.js](https://github.com/23/resumable.js/blob/master/samples/Backend%20with%20Python%20(Flask).md), and move the process of combining chunks into a Celery task. Hope to solve your problem.

Answer (score 44):

I think the super simple way to get around that simply sends the file in lots of small parts/chunks. So there are going to be two parts to making this work, the front-end (website) and backend (server).
For the front-end part, you can use something like `Dropzone.js` which has no additional dependencies and decent CSS included. All you have to do is add the class `dropzone` to a form and it automatically turns it into one of their special drag and drop fields (you can also click and select).

However, by default, dropzone does not chunk files. Luckily, it is really easy to enable. 
Here's a sample file upload form with `DropzoneJS` and `chunking` enabled:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/min/dropzone.min.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/min/basic.min.css"/>

    <script type="application/javascript" 
     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/min/dropzone.min.js">
    </script>

    <title>File Dropper</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action='/upload' class="dropzone dz-clickable" 
      id="dropper" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>

<script type="application/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.dropper = {
        paramName: 'file',
        chunking: true,
        forceChunking: true,
        url: '/upload',
        maxFilesize: 1025, // megabytes
        chunkSize: 1000000 // bytes
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And Here's the Back-end part using flask:

```
import logging
import os

from flask import render_template, Blueprint, request, make_response
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

from pydrop.config import config

blueprint = Blueprint('templated', __name__, template_folder='templates')

log = logging.getLogger('pydrop')


@blueprint.route('/')
@blueprint.route('/index')
def index():
    # Route to serve the upload form
    return render_template('index.html',
                           page_name='Main',
                           project_name="pydrop")


@blueprint.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']

    save_path = os.path.join(config.data_dir, secure_filename(file.filename))
    current_chunk = int(request.form['dzchunkindex'])

    # If the file already exists it's ok if we are appending to it,
    # but not if it's new file that would overwrite the existing one
    if os.path.exists(save_path) and current_chunk == 0:
        # 400 and 500s will tell dropzone that an error occurred and show an error
        return make_response(('File already exists', 400))

    try:
        with open(save_path, 'ab') as f:
            f.seek(int(request.form['dzchunkbyteoffset']))
            f.write(file.stream.read())
    except OSError:
        # log.exception will include the traceback so we can see what's wrong 
        log.exception('Could not write to file')
        return make_response(("Not sure why,"
                              " but we couldn't write the file to disk", 500))

    total_chunks = int(request.form['dztotalchunkcount'])

    if current_chunk + 1 == total_chunks:
        # This was the last chunk, the file should be complete and the size we expect
        if os.path.getsize(save_path) != int(request.form['dztotalfilesize']):
            log.error(f"File {file.filename} was completed, "
                      f"but has a size mismatch."
                      f"Was {os.path.getsize(save_path)} but we"
                      f" expected {request.form['dztotalfilesize']} ")
            return make_response(('Size mismatch', 500))
        else:
            log.info(f'File {file.filename} has been uploaded successfully')
    else:
        log.debug(f'Chunk {current_chunk + 1} of {total_chunks} '
                  f'for file {file.filename} complete')

    return make_response(("Chunk upload successful", 200))
```

Comment: I think this is the productable solution.up for you.

Comment: This was very helpful for us.  Also found what looks like the original article, which was even more helpful:  https://codecalamity.com/uploading-large-files-by-chunking-featuring-python-flask-and-dropzone-js/

Comment: This helped me a lot, but I think you don't need the `f.seek([...]` line, since you're opening the file in append mode. At least, I tried here and I worked without that line.

Answer (score 6):

Use `copy_current_request_context`,it will duplicate the context `request`.so you can use thread or anything else to make your task running background.

maybe an example will make it be clear.i have test it by a 3.37G file-debian-9.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso.

```
# coding:utf-8

from flask import Flask,render_template,request,redirect,url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
from time import sleep
from flask import copy_current_request_context
import threading
import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST','GET'])
def upload():
    @copy_current_request_context
    def save_file(closeAfterWrite):
        print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + " i am doing")
        f = request.files['file']
        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
        upload_path = os.path.join(basepath, '',secure_filename(f.filename)) 
        f.save(upload_path)
        closeAfterWrite()
        print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + " write done")
    def passExit():
        pass
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f= request.files['file']
        normalExit = f.stream.close
        f.stream.close = passExit
        t = threading.Thread(target=save_file,args=(normalExit,))
        t.start()
        return redirect(url_for('upload'))
    return render_template('upload.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is tempalte,it should be templates\upload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>example</h1>
    <form action="" enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST'>
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When uploading a file, you just can't leave the page and have it continue. The page has to stay opened in order to continue the upload.

Something you could do is open a new tab just for handling the upload and alerting the user when they inadvertently close the new tab before the upload finishes. That way the upload will be separate from whatever the user is doing on the original page so they can still navigate without cancelling the upload. The upload tab can also just close itself when it finishes.

index.js

```
    // get value from <input id="upload" type="file"> on page
    var upload = document.getElementById('upload');
    upload.addEventListener('input', function () {
        // open new tab and stick the selected file in it
        var file = upload.files[0];
        var uploadTab = window.open('/upload-page', '_blank');
        if (uploadTab) {
            uploadTab.file = file;
        } else {
            alert('Failed to open new tab');
        }
    });
```

upload-page.js

```
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
        return 'The upload will cancel if you leave the page, continue?';
    });
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.addEventListener('progress', function (evt) {
            var percentage = '' + (evt.loaded / evt.total * 100) + '%';
            // use percentage to update progress bar or something
        });
        req.addEventListener('load', function () {
            alert('Upload Finished');
            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload');
            window.close();
        });
        req.addRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        req.open('POST', '/upload/'+encodeURIComponent(window.file.name));
        req.send(window.file);
    });
```

On the server, you can use request.stream to read the uploaded file in chunks to avoid having to wait for the entire thing to load up in memory first.

server.py

```
@app('/upload/<filename>', methods=['POST'])
def upload(filename):
    filename = urllib.parse.unquote(filename)
    bytes_left = int(request.headers.get('content-length'))
    with open(os.path.join('uploads', filename), 'wb') as upload:
        chunk_size = 5120
        while bytes_left > 0:
            chunk = request.stream.read(chunk_size)
            upload.write(chunk)
            bytes_left -= len(chunk)
        return make_response('Upload Complete', 200)
```

You might be able to use FormData api instead of an octet-stream, but I'm not sure if you can stream those in flask.