# Dropzone Large file upload Not Working

Tags: jquery, dropzone

I use dropzone to upload files to the database, but there is a bit of a problem.
when I upload a file with a small size it works fine, but when I upload a file above 3 MB it does not work (
dropzone does not provide post value and does not save file to database)

this is my script:

```
var file_upload = new Dropzone(
        '#file-a-form-element', //id of drop zone element 1
        {
           url: "<?php echo base_url('dashboard/uploads_file') ?>",
    maxFilesize: 50,
    method:"post",
    acceptedFiles:".zip",
    paramName:"userfile",
    dictInvalidFileType:"file not allowed",
    addRemoveLinks:false,
        }
    );
```

Have a great day

Comment: what does not work ? what is the issue ? is the issue from dropzone widget, or from your server side ?

Comment: @StéphaneAmmar 
dropzone does not provide post value and does not save file to server

Comment: dropzone does not save the file to server, just send it to server. What is the log error ?

Comment: nothing show error, just blank

Comment: perhaps a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727052/handling-large-file-uploads-with-flask  help you