# How to upload large (~100Mb) files?

Tags: python, flask

I have following flask app

fileform.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple file upload using Python Flask</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/getSignature" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          Choose the file: <input type="file" name="photo"/><BR>
              <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def fileFrontPage():
    return render_template('fileform.html')

@app.route("/getSignature", methods=['POST'])
def handleFileUpload():
    if 'photo' in request.files:
        photo = request.files['photo']
        if photo.filename != '':
            filepath = os.path.join('/flask/files', photo.filename)
            photo.save(filepath)
    return render_template('result.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

This works for smaller files, but fails for larger file. 
After clicking **Upload** button, browser shows `(Uploading 13%..)` and then browser timeout with `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. Don't see any error in flask app.

I am serving this through Nginx. When I check nginx logs I see

```
2020/02/20 22:38:47 [error] 6#6: *170614 client intended to send too large body: 80762097 bytes, client: 10.2.16.178, server: localhost, request: "POST /getSignature
```

Is there any Nginx config I need to add for this ?

I want to upload files upto size 100Mb.

Comment: How are you running app.py? In the console/an ide or is it being run through a web server like apache/nginx?

Comment: Please don't say that you're using the dev server

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727052/handling-large-file-uploads-with-flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the content length is limited to a default value.

As you are using nginx, probably the upstream timeout it playing its game (default for upstream `keepalive_timeout 60s`) 
add the following setting to nginx:

```
keepalive_timeout 900s;

#extra
proxy_read_timeout 900s;
uwsgi_read_timeout 900s;
```

More tunning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20678783/5476782)

And if you use a python wsgi server like uwsgi, set also the [keep alive](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#http-keepalive) there:

```
http-keepalive 900;
```

Comment: Adding `client_max_body_size 100M;` to Nginx config fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

From https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/ :

> Connection Reset Issue
>
> When using the local development server, you
>   may get a connection reset error instead of a 413 response. You will
>   get the correct status response when running the app with a production
>   WSGI server.

Solution: don't use the development server, setup a real WSGI server

Comment: Link to the deployment options and I'll happily upvote

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/ but I feel there is something else in this problem

Comment: @roganjosh turns out it's not related, as the OP is running behind nginx and that's where the connection reset happens

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into chunking? It allows you to break up files and data into discrete pieces to send over the wire. And you'll have two main parts: the front-end and the backend. For the front-end you can use something like [Dropzone.js.](https://www.dropzonejs.com) However you'll need to enable the chunking behavior, as by default it isn't included. Luckily, it is really easy to enable.

This might be completed like so:

```
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/min/dropzone.min.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/min/basic.min.css"/>

    <script type="application/javascript"
     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/min/dropzone.min.js">
    </script>
    <head>
        <title>Simple file upload using Python Flask</title>
    </head>
        <form method="POST" action='/upload' class="dropzone dz-clickable"
                    id="dropper" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        </form>

        <script type="application/javascript">
                Dropzone.options.dropper = {
                        paramName: 'file',
                        chunking: true,
                        forceChunking: true,
                        url: '/upload',
                        maxFilesize: 1025, // megabytes
                        chunkSize: 1000000 // bytes
                }
        </script>
</html>
```

And the following flask example will handle the back-end:

```
import logging
import os

from flask import render_template, Blueprint, request, make_response
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

from pydrop.config import config

blueprint = Blueprint('templated', __name__, template_folder='templates')

log = logging.getLogger('pydrop')


@blueprint.route('/')
@blueprint.route('/index')
def index():
    # Route to serve the upload form
    return render_template('index.html',
                           page_name='Main',
                           project_name="pydrop")


@blueprint.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']

    save_path = os.path.join(config.data_dir, secure_filename(file.filename))
    current_chunk = int(request.form['dzchunkindex'])

    # If the file already exists it's ok if we are appending to it,
    # but not if it's new file that would overwrite the existing one
    if os.path.exists(save_path) and current_chunk == 0:
        # 400 and 500s will tell dropzone that an error occurred and show an error
        return make_response(('File already exists', 400))

    try:
        with open(save_path, 'ab') as f:
            f.seek(int(request.form['dzchunkbyteoffset']))
            f.write(file.stream.read())
    except OSError:
        # log.exception will include the traceback so we can see what's wrong 
        log.exception('Could not write to file')
        return make_response(("Not sure why,"
                              " but we couldn't write the file to disk", 500))

    total_chunks = int(request.form['dztotalchunkcount'])

    if current_chunk + 1 == total_chunks:
        # This was the last chunk, the file should be complete and the size we expect
        if os.path.getsize(save_path) != int(request.form['dztotalfilesize']):
            log.error(f"File {file.filename} was completed, "
                      f"but has a size mismatch."
                      f"Was {os.path.getsize(save_path)} but we"
                      f" expected {request.form['dztotalfilesize']} ")
            return make_response(('Size mismatch', 500))
        else:
            log.info(f'File {file.filename} has been uploaded successfully')
    else:
        log.debug(f'Chunk {current_chunk + 1} of {total_chunks} '
                  f'for file {file.filename} complete')

    return make_response(("Chunk upload successful", 200))
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting a much more reasonable solution than the "raise the cap and increase the timeouts" that gets suggested everywhere

Comment: @Taylor Cochran does chunking speed up the uploading by any change ? Using the file.save() method with files over 600mb its taking +2 hours for me