upload large file to s3 through a Flask REST API | don't want to use s3 presigned url
I am developing a Flask API which take the file in input as PUT/POST request and uploads the file to s3 bucket.
I am using upload_fileObj method of boto3.
**Note - I don't want to use s3 presigned url.
**
Now the problem I am facing is it's eating lot of memory of my kubernetes pod.
Like if a file is 2 GB, it eats up 2 GB of memory leaving no space for other files to upload.
so the scalability of the application is getting hindered.
what are the possible solutions for the same?
One solution I can think of is streaming the file data directly to s3 but I can't figure out an efficient solution for this.
I even tried the TransferConfig but it doesn't seems to add any benefit here.
transfer_config = TransferConfig(
            multipart_threshold = 1024 * 1024 * 100, # 100MB threshold for multipart transfer
            max_concurrency = 10, # Number of threads for parallel transfer
            multipart_chunksize = 1024 * 1024 * 25, # 25MB per part
            max_io_queue = 100, # Maximum number of queued I/O operations
            io_chunksize= 1024 * 1024 * 1, # Size of each I/O chunk (1MB)
            use_threads = True,   
        )


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727052/handling-large-file-uploads-with-flask

Does this answer your question? Handling large file uploads with Flask

To address the memory issue when uploading large files to S3 using a Flask API in a Kubernetes environment, you can implement streaming uploads to S3. This approach will allow you to upload the file in chunks, thus reducing the memory footprint of your application.
Modify the Flask API to Handle Streaming:
Use Flask's request stream to handle large file uploads in chunks.
You can use the werkzeug library's FileStorage class to manage file uploads in Flask.
Upload to S3 in Chunks:
Use Boto3's multipart upload feature to upload the file in chunks.
